# How do one run PHP-FPM on subdomain?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php-fpm, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I run Apache 2.4 and PHP-FPM via ProxyPassmatch in httpd.conf, not vhost (*for what it's worth*):

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1/home/user/www
```

I wanted to create a subdomain to run a CMS on but quickly I figured out that PHP files aren't being processed on that subdomain probably due to my lack of understanding how to set it up.

I'm not sure whether I need to create a vhost with separate ProxyPassMatch directive or default one above will work.

**httpd.conf:**

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local"
Listen 192.168.1.2:80

LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/apache24/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module libexec/apache24/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache24/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/apache24/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/apache24/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache24/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module libexec/apache24/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/apache24/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/apache24/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module libexec/apache24/mod_filter.so
LoadModule deflate_module libexec/apache24/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule mime_module libexec/apache24/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module libexec/apache24/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module libexec/apache24/mod_env.so
LoadModule expires_module libexec/apache24/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache24/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/apache24/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache24/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module libexec/apache24/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule unixd_module libexec/apache24/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/apache24/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache24/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache24/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module libexec/apache24/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache24/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache24/mod_rewrite.so

IncludeOptional etc/apache24/modules.d/[0-9][0-9][0-9]_*.conf

<IfModule unixd_module>

User www
Group www

</IfModule>

ServerAdmin user@mail.com
ServerName 192.168.1.2:80

<Directory />

    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied

</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/home/user/www"

<Directory "/home/user/www">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">

    Require all denied

</Files>

ErrorLog "/var/log/apache/error.log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "/var/log/apache/access.log" combined

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/www/apache24/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<Directory "/usr/local/www/apache24/cgi-bin">

    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied

</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>

    TypesConfig etc/apache24/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z

</IfModule>

EnableMMAP On

Include etc/apache24/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
Include etc/apache24/extra/httpd-default.conf
Include etc/apache24/extra/h5bp.conf
Include etc/apache24/Includes/*.conf

ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1/home/user/www
```

**subdomain vhost:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "/home/user/www/xxx"
    ServerName xxx.domain.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php 

<Directory "/home/user/www/xxx">

    AllowOverride FileInfo
    Require all granted

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**default php-fpm pool:**

```
[global]
pid = run/php-fpm.pid
error_log = log/php/error.log

[www]
user = user
group = user

listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock
listen.owner = user
listen.group = user
listen.mode = 0660

listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3

access.log = /var/log/php/access.log
access.format = "%R - %u %t \"%m %r%Q%q\" %s %f %{mili}d %{kilo}M %C%%"

chdir = /home/user/www

catch_workers_output = yes

security.limit_extensions = .php
env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

**In Cloudflare I set up a CNAME record pointing to xxx.domain.com:**
[image: Cloudflare CNAME]

**All I get in browser is:**

`"File not found"`

**and in logs:**

`[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 44810] [client xxx.xx.x.xxx] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'`

I would appreciate a hint/push in right direction.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to do anything for PHP to process files on a particular domain, you only have to instruct your webserver to pass files to PHP in each vhost where you want PHP to be handled. PHP-FPM doesn't concern itself with what domain it's serving PHP for.

Comment: any chance of an example?

Comment: I hope so! _You_ need to provide _us_ an example of what you tried and what is going wrong.

Comment: Updated question with configs.

Comment: @purpler - Please don't make us go elsewhere for your configs. Put the relevant bits into a proper code block in your question.

Comment: Sorry. Updated.

Comment: Hope it looks ok now.

Answer (score 0):

In each of your virtual hosts you will need to place:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/your/documentroot/$1
```

Place this right at the top of Virtual Hosts config so that it is not effected by anything that follows.

Each Virtual Host needs a different port so 9000 then 9001 then 9002 etc. These ports must match the ones you use in your pools eg `listen = 127.0.0.1:9001`. You will need to match up the users etc too.

This wiki provides further info: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM .

You say you are using `Apache 2.4`, it is worth noting that you cannot use sockets prior to Apache 2.4.9, hence why I didn't use them in my example.

Answer (score 0):

If that can help, all you need for massive hosting under apache httpd is the mod_vhost_alias module, you only set up one generic virtualhost with can handle pretty all scenarios as explain on the apache documentation here: [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html)

I'm using it myself to redirect all my productions client php from sub.domain.tld to my php-fpm production which is chrooted.

I've got a document root like /home/clientname(as sub ;-) )/www/

Then a proxypassmatch with fastcgi://host:port/%(1/2/etc depending what part of the name you're looking for)/www/

PS: you only need different pool/ports if you really planned to segment you calls to different types of php-fpm pools as in multiple environments (prod/development/demo/etc) or with multiple clients in the event of a trully worried mind about segmentation.

I hope my answer could help the op or another people if it's too late for the op ;-)